# Prove: if tree has n vertices, it has n-1 edges

Tags: tree, induction

This is question number 1-17 in the "Algorithm Design Manual 2nd Ed." by Steven S. Skiena.

I found a solution to this question here, http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/TDK/FINAL/Chap%204.PDF.

However, I wanted to know if this constitutes an acceptable **proof by induction**?

Base case: when n = 1, there is a single node with no edges.  It is self-evident that there are n - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0 edges.

Inductive step:

1. Suppose every tree with n vertices has n - 1 edges.
2. Given a tree *T* with n + 1 vertices, this tree must be equivalent to a tree of n vertices, *T'*, plus 1 *leaf node*.
3. By the hypothesis, *edges(T') = n - 1*.
4. Since a leaf node is connected to one, and only one other node, then adding it to *T'* will add only one edge.
5. Therefore, *edges(T) = edges(T') + 1 = n - 1 + 1 = n*.  QED.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll change it.

Comment: My initial suggestion (to strengthen the induction assumption in the particular way I suggested) does not seem to be helpful after some thought. Still, your statement "this tree must be equivalent to a tree of n vertices, T', plus 1 leaf node" is neither obvious, neither clearly stated (what is this "equivalence"? What is this "plus"?).

Comment: I think you need to add step between 1 and 2 which prove that your tree T **has** leaf. Also you need to say (as obvious as it is) that after removing the leaf, the rest of the graph is actually **tree** (=no circles created during edge removal - which is true but need to be statement)